# c# thermal image server stream for workstation client

Tags: c#, tcp, camera, udp

I am Tommaso and I have just signed up.I would like to open a new this discussion hoping it could be  interesting.
I am working with thermal camera(C# ,Visual studio 2012,windows 7 -x64)  and I have already create a server that performs the following task:

1. Get raw frame from camera
2. Eventually rotation
3. Convert raw pixel value to Kelvin
4. Calculate min , avg and max pixel in a frame
5. Check temperature alert ,alarm.

Now I am asked to allow 4 work stations to see the real time thermal frames stream from cameras. Unfortunately in this project these are located in a real wide area at many meters (600-700 m) from main server. At 3,75 frame/s, frame resolution of 640x512 pixel and  pixel depth of 14 bit (16) we are talking about 2,5Mbyte per second. No compression is provided.

So I decide to use the frames arrived at the server creating a socket to listen for 1 or 4 work stations need  the stream. So each time a client connects, I create a dedicate queue where the main thread enqueues frames and where the socket thread dequeues and sends them to the connected client.

**Here is my question**: Due to importance of a single frame do you suggest to use the reliable and heaviest TCP or a the simplest UDP considering the amount of flow?

Sorry for my prolixity but it's just for an explanation .
If you want to know more about my project please ask .

Tommaso

Comment: one thing to consider is the hardware you are using for networking. I have run into problems in the past with UDP on some older routers and access points. If you have a direct connection this is not a problem, but if you are networking it may be.

Comment: thank you guys. Hardware is good and dedicated so as Mustafa said i will probably use an Udp enviorement.

Answer (score 1):

You want to stream video. If a frame doesn't reach to it's destination, there would be no problem. Because after 250ms (I'll assume your video is 4 fps) another frame will be sent. Since every frame is not viral, you better use UDP.